# How to tell is apache is configured to use perl?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, perl

I've spent enough time looking around for answers to this with google and I give up.  Plenty of discussions about how to build apache with perl support but I want to find out how to tell if the apache that comes with RHEL6.2 already has perl built in.  I'm betting is it, but I have an httpd conf file that I've been using on RHEL apache servers since RHEL3 and it always just worked by dropping it into /etc/httpd/conf.d/ but now I tried it on RHEL6.2 and it just lists the source of my script as if perl isn't enabled.  I figure the very first step is to verify perl is enabled and then step 2 will be to find out what's wrong with my configuration.

-mark

Answer (score 2):

You can list the loaded modules in the stock RHEL/CentOS Apache with `httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have mod_perl installed?

```
$ yum info mod_perl
Available Packages
Name        : mod_perl
Arch        : i686
Version     : 2.0.4
Release     : 10.el6
Size        : 3.2 M
Repo        : base
Summary     : An embedded Perl interpreter for the Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://perl.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : Mod_perl incorporates a Perl interpreter into the Apache web server,
            : so that the Apache web server can directly execute Perl code.
            : Mod_perl links the Perl runtime library into the Apache web server and
            : provides an object-oriented Perl interface for Apache's C language
            : API.  The end result is a quicker CGI script turnaround process, since
            : no external Perl interpreter has to be started.
            : 
            : Install mod_perl if you're installing the Apache web server and you'd
            : like for it to directly incorporate a Perl interpreter.
```

If not, then "yum install mod_perl".  It should drop a file in conf.d/ that should load the module.

Comment: excellent, so mod_perl IS installed, which is what I would have expected.  In fact I just copied my script to the cgi-bin directory and it does execute, so now for the more exotic because that's now what I want.

Comment: And you have the right ScriptAlias or AddHandler directives in the running configuration?